# Installing glfw3 on ubuntu 13.04 - make error

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, glfw

I downloaded glfw 3.0.2 and trying to install it onto Ubuntu 13.04. (Running Amd radeon drivers 13.08 beta - if that is any relevance.)

I followed the readme and installed `xorg-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev`. I then run 'cmake .' and then 'make' and get these errors:

```
$ make

Scanning dependencies of target glfw
[  2%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o
[  4%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o
[  8%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o
[ 24%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o
[ 26%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o
[ 34%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o
[ 36%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o
/home/dean/Downloads/glfw-3.0.2/src/glx_context.c: In function ‘_glfwPlatformGetProcAddress’:
/home/dean/Downloads/glfw-3.0.2/src/glx_context.c:598:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘dlsym’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from /home/dean/Downloads/glfw-3.0.2/src/glx_platform.h:41:0,
             from /home/dean/Downloads/glfw-3.0.2/src/x11_platform.h:52,
             from /home/dean/Downloads/glfw-3.0.2/src/internal.h:69,
             from /home/dean/Downloads/glfw-3.0.2/src/glx_context.c:28:
/usr/include/dlfcn.h:65:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘const GLubyte *’
Linking C static library libglfw3.a
[ 36%] Built target glfw
Scanning dependencies of target boing
[ 38%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/boing.c.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so', needed by `examples/boing'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
$
```

Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

check if /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so exists. 
If no, use "apt-file search libGL.so" to find out in which package this file lies. Then install this package.

You may also try to make a symlink, as this file should be a symlink to some other .so file like libGL.so.x.y, where x and y are version numbers.

Comment: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so' exists. Properties says "Type: Link (broken) (inode/symlink)" and "Link target: mesa/libGL.so".

'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so' also exists. Properties also say "Type: Link (broken)" and "Link target: libGL.so.1.2.0".

In the same /mesa/ directoy there is no 'libGL.so.1.2.0' but instead a 'FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2.0'

Comment: @Dio: there are two things you can do: recreate symlink pointing to one of those .so files (../mesa/libGL.so) or to FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2.0. You can also figure out why is this symlink broken (reinstall package responsible for this symlink may help). you may also try to find out why target file doesn't exist (find package responsible for it and try to (re)install it)

Comment: I reverted from the beta driver (13.8 beta) down to the stable driver 13.4. (It also dropped from OpenGL 4.3 down to 4.2) and make just works now. A problem with the beta driver??

Comment: @Dio: hard to say, I'm not using ubuntu, so I cannot verify what happend, but you can do your own investingation by listing files of packages

Answer (score 1):

**This is what worked for me (Using Ubuntu 13.10):**

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

---

This should work, but if you get an error like this:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so’: File exists
```

Try deleting the symlink or renaming it to something else and re-trying the above command. In my case it was pointing to an unknown file `libGL.so.1.2.0`.

Comment: FYI: You can rename it by doing `sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.original`

Answer (score 0):

*For proprietary drivers see update & warning below*

Try reinstalling `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` wich renews the `libGL.so` symlink without manual interference.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx
```

This worked for: Debian Wheezy

**Update & Warning:**

Turn's out the reinstallation of `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` renewed - as expected - the `libGL.so` symlink, but also broke my proprietary nvidia driver installation. After reinstalling the driver everything's fine. So in that case, it might be a good idea to just reinstall your proprietary driver.